# Make network-manager use ETH and WLAN interfaces at the same time

Tags: networking

I am having this issue not being able to use WiFi and ethernet at the same time.
As soon as I plug ethernet cable network manager disables WiFi.

Is there any v=config option for NM not do that?

Comment: Please add your operating system ... :/

Comment: Hi sorry I was assuming things, my bad. A will add the answer also.

Answer (score 0):

After asking a question I have googled the answer. Some laptops have option in BIOS to enable disable on/off wireless switch. I was accusing network-manager but problem was hardware.